# Is there a way in Python to utilize infinite subsets of R or C?

Tags: python

I understand that it is intrinsically impossible for computers to store infinite sets (aside from the use of generators to produce countably infinite sets), but I was wondering if there's a way to represent, say, the set of complex numbers with |z| < 1. I know I could do this with comprehensions if a package has a "set of all complex numbers" object, but my initial searches has come up empty.

I presume the better way to deal with such sets is to test inclusion given a number (i.e., given z is |z| <1?) rather than try to have some type of object, but just thought I'd ask. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with such a set? Iteration? Containment test?

Comment: These sets would primarily be used as mathematical objects in a theory that I'm trying to write a module about for purposes of investigation and modeling. I guess important features off the top of my head would be checking containment of matrix eigenvalues (and containment in the boundary), graphing to visualize the set, and determining if one set is contained in the other. Luckily most of these sets are shifted circle interiors, so perhaps I'm best off defining the object as a center and radius coupled with methods to graph and test inclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a class to abstract away the `<` test:

```
>>> class complex_subset(object):
...     def __init__(self, norm_below):
...         self.norm_below=norm_below
...     def __contains__(self, item):
...         return abs(complex(item)) < self.norm_below
... 
>>> complex_below_norm_1=complex_subset(norm_below=1)
>>> 0 in complex_below_norm_1
True
>>> 3 in complex_below_norm_1
False
>>> 0.5+0.5j in complex_below_norm_1
True
```

and of course, you can generalize `complex_subset` with keyword `__init__` arguments to define your `__contains__` method.

If you want to be able to compare `complex_subset`s with each other, you have to write the appropriate `__eq__`, `__gt__` and `__lt__` methods.

Comment: I think this is the best way to handle these objects for my prose, thanks for the sample code.